# Fetching data from Postgres database is slow using native query in Springboot

Tags: java, spring-boot, entitymanager, postgresql-9.3, nativequery

I am using 2 methods to fetch data from Postgres database. But it is taking more time to render than usual. what could be the solution.

Below is my code:

1st one to get table name

```
@Override
    public List getTablename(String reportId, String userId) {
    List tableName = null;
    try {
    tableName = entityManager.createNativeQuery("select reporttablename from report_notifications "
    + "where reportid ="+"'"+reportId+"'"+"and userid="+"'"+userId+"'"+" order by id desc limit 1;").getResultList();
    }catch(Exception e) {
    logger.error("Exception",e);
    }
    return tableName;
    }
```

2nd one to get data based on table name

```
@Override
public List findAllTempTableDatas(List tableName) {
List<Object[]> tempList = null;
try {
if (!tableName.isEmpty()) {
tempList = entityManager.createNativeQuery("select * from "+tableName.get(0)+";").getResultList();
}
} catch (Exception e) {
logger.error("Exception",e);
}
return tempList;
}
```

I am using these 2 methods directly in controller class to call an API. It works fine. but time consumption is more. How to reduce it.

Comment: As you are performing select * from Query, how much approx data (records) do you have in your table(s)? if it is huge then better to have some limit with server side pagination concept, you can fetch data with the chunks each time

Comment: @NitinDhomse data size is not fixed, it depends on client. It may usually have large data. Can u plz add pagination concept solution here